# Python logging module - no output to log file on raspberry pi but works on Mac OS

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have setup a logger for my script that works perfectly on my mac. But I need this program to be running 24/7 on my raspberry pi. However, when it runs on there the log file just remains blank for some odd reason.

Here is how I am setting up the logger

```
import logging
import ...
import ... 

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='log_file.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

and later using in my methods by just calling `logger.debug('[msg here]')`

I dont know why this is happening, is there a different way to setup the logger on raspbian/linux than with mac os??

Comment: Have you checked that the script has write permissions on the log file on the raspberry?

Comment: Also check what the current working directory is on the raspberry. Maybe the logs are just somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with logging that was not supposed to happen (I searched a lot for answers, but found none)

In the end, I looked in `/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py` to see it.
In my case, when I used the `basicConfig`, it says that if a handler already exists (`logging.root.handlers`) nothing will happen (similar to your case I believe).

So, I just make it empty with `logging.root.handlers = [ ]` after importing `logging` module and it started to log to the file.

I don't know if it is exactly the same for you, but I would try this or take a look in the functions that your calling inside the above file path (just be aware of the python version that you are using).

Hope it helps!